# ReactNative : permission always return 'never ask again'

Tags: android, react-native

am using following code base to request the permission but it always return 'never ask again'

```
 async requestPermission(request){
        try{
           const response= await PermissionsAndroid.request('PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA',{
            'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
            'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                       'so you can take awesome pictures.'
          })
           console.log(response)
        }catch(err){

        }
        this.getcurrentLocation()
    }
```

//Response never_ask_again

Comment: Have you added the permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: yes, nothing happening

Comment: i have the same issue any idea ?

Comment: for it was build error, clean and rebuild the app finally it worked. Make sure that you have added the permission in the manifest file

Comment: @Bytecode update the answer :)

Comment: I did clean and rebuild several times and finally started working, somehow the build cache is not properly updating. @GokulKulkarni

Comment: Yes @Bytecode that worked for me too, I meant if you update the same thing as answer, instead in comment, it will be more appropriate for us.

Comment: take a look at this page which is related to permissions that requires user prompt.just add your specific permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.I fix my problem in this way.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced this issue about LOCATION service permission.
I forgot to add android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in AndroidManifest.xml.

So, I think you also forgot to add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`
in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

I did clean and rebuild several times and finally started working, somehow the build cache is not properly updating.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to handle such situations is to open settings and direct the users directly to adapt the right, see below example:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

const openSettings = () => {
  Linking.openSettings();
};

const askForPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      {
        title: 'Storage Permission',
        message: 'App needs access to your storage to read files',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      },
    );
    if (result === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('Storage Permission Granted.');
    } else if (result === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED) {
      console.log('Storage Permission Denied.');
    } else if (result === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) {
      console.log('Storage Permission Denied with Never Ask Again.');
      Alert.alert(
        'Storage Permission Required',
        'App needs access to your storage to read files. Please go to app settings and grant permission.',
        [
          { text: 'Cancel', style: 'cancel' },
          { text: 'Open Settings', onPress: openSettings },
        ],
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `tools:node="remove"` from AndroidManifest.xml fixed mine.
Replace
`<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`
with
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/issues/504#issuecomment-914417383